# Bash programming — how to add string into text file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, linux-mint

```
touch log.txt
while [ 1 ]; do 
 echo "insert data: "
 read data
 if [ $data = "finish" ]; then
  break
 fi
 echo "$data" >> log.txt
```

When I run the program and type in a word in an input like "hello im martin", it gives me an error saying unexpected operator. How to fix this?

Comment: Do you have a final line written `done`, right? :)

Comment: @FernandoAires: the script wouldn't get as far as running to get the input and then fail on the 'unexpected operator' if the `done` was missing.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a `done` keyword after your echo statement that signifies the end of the `while` loop.

Additionally, you should put the `$data` on line 5 in quotes, otherwise the `hello im martin` input will cause that line to be interpreted as:

```
if [ hello im martin = "finish" ]; then
```

Comment: And, in Bash, the other option is to use the `[[ … ]]` operator to do the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

while [ 1 ]; do

echo "insert data:"; read data

if [ "$data" == "finish" ]; then

break;

fi

echo "$data" >> log.txt;

done